# How to run XDMan (Xtream Download Manager) on Ubuntu Startup?

Tags: startup-applications

Does someone knows the commands on running XDMan on startup? Or at least the app directory of XDMan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the exact command first browse to `File System` => `usr` => `share` => `applications`
(This is your required app directory)

Here you can find all of your application shortcut. Click <kbd>Right button</kbd> on 'Xtreme download manager' > select `properties` > copy the `command`

[image]

To enable an application on startup you have to set that on `startup application`.

Go to `dashboard`

Now search for `startup` and open `Startup applications`

Click <kbd>Add</kbd> button

Now set name as `xdm` and paste the `command`

[image]

Click <kbd>Add</kbd>. Now it's done.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine.. but how to minimize xdman to systray at startup in ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your dash home.
2. Search for Startup Application.
3. Click add button, and set XDMan as name, xdman for commands, and write your review at comment column.
4. Click add.
5. Now XDMan will be startup application

Thanks anyway